# How join 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have trouble. How to join 2 table query. if data table:

Table 1: 
CustomerID : 1,2,3,4,5

Customercode : cus1,cus9,cus4,null,null

Customername: roya,almudena,jack,jane, Francisco

Table 2 :
CustomerID : 1,2,3,4

Customercode : cus1,cus2,cus9,null

Customername: roya,jose,almudena,jane

Q: what is query to show all name from 2 table (no duplicate name).

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: use union all function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `JOIN` for this, you need a `UNION` statement

```
select distinct name from table1
union
select distinct name from table2
```

if you use `union all` it will create duplicates, but `union` on its own will not.

you could wrap it in `select distinct name from ()` as well if you want to be extra safe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer 

Comment: Mr.Alan can ask another question ? 
What is query to show name only Jose(table 2) and Francisco (table 1) from 2 table ?

Comment: you should ask a new question, but the answer, if I understood you correctly, is `select distinct name from table1 where name = 'Francisco' union select distinct name from table2 where name = 'Jose'.` Note sure how that helps you though.

Comment: `distinct` is unneeded, because `union` without `all` does the same thing. "Extra safety" (outer query) in this context is nonsense - you either get correct result or not, adding layers of identical functionality makes code only more messy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no duplicate names within each table (as in your sample data), I strongly suggest:

```
select t1.customername
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.customername
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.customername = t2.customername);
```

This should have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use union statement :

```
select distinct Customername from table1
union
select distinct Customername from table2
```